# How to stop skipping lines of VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro that serves to validate data ("Validate") as part of a larger macro ("report"). My issue is that a small part of this validate macro won't run when I run the report macro; although, the validate macro will run perfectly if I run it separately after receiving the whole report. The chunk of code in bold is the offending section. What really confuses me is that the "Check Arrival Sheet" section, which is identical except for names, works perfectly.
I've tried things like `DoEvents` and the like, with no success. Any ideas?

Thanks

```
Sub Check_Ammo_type()
'
' Ensures DATX compatability
' Checks Departure Sheet
Sheets("Departures").Range("O3").Formula = "=Count(DepDesign)"
Sheets("Departures").Range("O4").Formula = "=Count(DepOptimized)"
Sheets("Departures").Range("P3").Formula = "=IF(DepOptimized[@Dest]=DepDesign[@Dest],""Check"",""Yikes"")"
**With Range("M2").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
        Selection.FillDown
        End With
Range("Q3").Formula = "=COUNTIF(P:P,""=Yikes"")"**
If Sheets("Departures").Range("Q3").Value > 0 Then
     MsgBox "Market mismatch. Please ensure that design and optimized DAT files have the same markets."
    End If
If Sheets("Departures").Range("O3").Value <> Sheets("Departures").Range("O4").Value Then
     MsgBox "Frequency mismatch. Please ensure that design and optimized DAT files have same frequencies."
    End If
Columns("O:Q").Hidden = True

' Checks Arrival Sheet
Sheets("Arrivals").Range("O3").Formula = "=Count(ArrDesign)"
Sheets("Arrivals").Range("O4").Formula = "=Count(ArrOptimized)"
Sheets("Arrivals").Range("P3").Formula = "=IF(ArrOptimized[@Orig]=ArrDesign[@Orig],""Check"",""Yikes"")"
        With Range("M2").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
        Selection.FillDown
        End With
Range("Q3").Formula = "=COUNTIF(P:P,""=Yikes"")"
If Sheets("Arrivals").Range("Q3").Value > 0 Then
     MsgBox "Market mismatch. Please ensure that design and optimized DAT files have the same markets."
End If
If Sheets("Arrivals").Range("O3").Value <> Sheets("Arrivals").Range("O4").Value Then
     MsgBox "Frequency mismatch. Please ensure that design and optimized DAT files have same frequencies."
End If
Columns("O:Q").Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: the chunk in bold? which chuck is that?

Comment: Have you tried walking through the macro using f8? From what I can see, it seems that the range("M2") filldown may be overriding the first iteration. Try specifying what sheet M2 is such as : With Sheets("Departures").Range("M2").select for the first one and Sheets("Arrivals").range("M2").select for the second. Sometimes if Screenupdate is paused, the screen won't change to the sheet you intend to use so clarification is needed.

Comment: ^^ **always** qualify `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, etc to specify which sheet they refer to unless you **know** that you are wanting to work with the `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: @TJYen That was the fix! The Departures sheet wasn't active when it tried to run the fill down procedure. It's always the little things I miss, so helps to have had an extra set of eyes.